# JOINing Three SQL Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a working SQL query, but I need to grab another piece of data from a third table in the query for ease of use, but have been unable to grab it.

Every table is basically tied together by `tenant_id`

(I apologize for the bad structure, I didn't create the DB)

**TABLE: tenant_statements**

tenant_id    balance    property    date

**TABLE: leases**

lease_id    tenant_id    property    unit_number

**TABLE: tenants**

tenant_id    first_name    last_name    global_comment

My current query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tenant_statements t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT * 
FROM leases
GROUP BY tenant_id
ORDER BY lease_id
)l ON t.tenant_id = l.tenant_id
WHERE t.date = '$date'
AND t.property = '$property'
ORDER BY t.balance DESC
```

This give's me the appropriate response for joining the two tables: `leases` and `tenant_statements`. `$date` and `$property` are set via a PHP variable loop and used for presentation.

What I am attempting to do is also grab `tenants.global_comment` and have it added each result.

the ideal output will be:

tenant_statements t: t.balance, t.date

leases l: l.property, l.unit_number

tenants x: x.first_name, x.last_name, x.global_comment

All in one query.

Can anyone point me in to the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Whenever possible, it is best to avoid the wildcard for select statement ('SELECT * ...')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM    tenant_statements t INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM leases
            GROUP BY tenant_id
            ORDER BY lease_id
        )l ON t.tenant_id = l.tenant_id INNER JOIN
        tenants ts  ON  t.tenant_id = ts.tenant_id
WHERE   t.date = '$date'
AND     t.property = '$property'
ORDER BY    t.balance DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Although each join specification joins only two tables, FROM clauses can contain multiple join specifications. This allows many tables to be joined for a single query.

```
 SELECT  t.tenant_id,
t.balance,
l.unit_number,
l.property
x.first_name, x.last_name, x.global_comment


fROM  tenant_statements t
   INNER JOIN  leases l ON l.tenant_id = t .tenant_id
   INNER JOIN tenants x  on x.tenant_id = t.tenant_id
```